# Everything In my fresh Manjaro Install is zoomed out

Tags: manjaro

I dual booted my computer with Manjaro and everything seems zoomed out, I am not use it and unable to read texts in my ide (Intellij) or on firefox, i need to get real close with the screen. I tried using `xrandr -s 1920x1080` but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: which desktop are you using, i.e., is this Manjaro GNOME, or Manjaro XFCE or Manjaro Plasma desktop? You're looking for the "hi-dpi" setting, but where that setting is found is different for these different user interfaces :)

Comment: I am using Gnome @MarcusMüller

Comment: Settings > Devices > Displays > Scale

Comment: that doesn't help at all, I only have two option, 100% and 200% (am at 100%). selecting 200% just makes everything so extremly big.

Comment: I'd like to change the scale factor of the OS @MarcusMüller

Comment: that *is* the scale factor of the OS.